# How to check date(getting from json file) is before or after in android?

Tags: java, android, json

I am getting a date from JSON file, and it is in string format.I have two string values of date named startdate and enddate that is coming from intent to currentActivity. Now I want to check that, if date value coming from json file is after the startdate or before the enddate. How can I do this? And yes, the format I json file having is "yyyy-mm-dd".

JSON Data Look like:

{"posts":[{"start_date":"2013-02-15","end_date":"2013-02-21"}]}

Here is the code I have tried but I am getting output as **Mon Jan 07 00:00:00 GMT+5:30 2013**:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String startDate = intent.getStringExtra("startDate"); //I have check this. It is proper.
String endDate = intent.getStringExtra("endDate"); //I have check this. It is proper.

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date start = null,end = null;
try {
start = sdf.parse(startDate);
end = sdf.parse(endDate);
} catch (ParseException e1) {
e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is the code of comparing date:

```
Date date = null;  
try {
    date = sdf.parse(c.getString(TAG_DATE)); //I am getting the date from a json file here.
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Date currDate = new Date();
if (end.compareTo(currDate) < 0 || start.compareTo(currDate) < 0) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please select valid dates...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else if (end.compareTo(currDate) == 0 && start.compareTo(currDate) >= 0){
    if (date.after(start)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "After...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
} else if (end.compareTo(currDate) > 0  && start.compareTo(currDate) >= 0) {
        if (date.after(start) && date.before(end)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Before...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the date format in the JSON file?

Comment: What line gives the output that you describe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would prefer using a more robust approach that involves converting the date strings to actual [`Date`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html) (or [`Calendar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html)) objects:

```
String startDateString = ...; // get date string from json
String endDateString = ...; // get date string from json
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date start = formatter.parse(startDateString);
Date end = formatter.parse(endDateString);
```

From here on, you can use e.g. `start.before(end)` or `end.after(start)` to check whether a date comes before or after another date. If you need more fine-grained control, you can always get the date in milliseconds and have your logic work on that.

---

So you've updated your code, but you're leaving it up to us to figure out what's going on and, more importantly, what you're expecting to happen? It looks like you want to check how the current date relates to those retrieved from json, although I'm a little lost at what the fourth date field, named `date`, is for.

Just some remarks about the current snippet:

```
if (end.compareTo(currDate) < 0 || start.compareTo(currDate) < 0)
```

Personally, I find `before()` and `after()` much more readable and descriptive, but I suppose there's nothing wrong with using `compareTo()`. However, important to realize is that `0` will only be returned iff the underlying *millisecond* representations of two dates are equal. With that being said, I'm not sure how much sense it would make to do the first check in the following condition:

```
else if (end.compareTo(currDate) == 0 && start.compareTo(currDate) >= 0)
```

You'll have to be **really** lucky to get the milliseconds of `end` exactly identical to `currDate`. Unless you do some manipulation somewhere to normalize all the dates to e.g. midnight, it's unlikely `end.compareTo(currDate) == 0` will ever be true.

Regarding this normalization: have a look at the previously mentioned [`Calendar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) class. It'll allow you to easily retrieve the values for the separate fields of a datestamp/timestamp. For example, if you only want to compare the day, month and year, you can get those specific fields from a `Calendar` instance with a simple get call. Even more convenient is that you can also set every field independently - that's great for normalizing all dates to e.g. midnight or midday, after which you can still use the `before()` and `after()` methods.

I'm convinced that should give you enough pointers to correctly code up an implementation that fits your needs. Without exactly knowing what you're trying to achieve, I'm afraid I can't help you any further.

Comment: Hey I tried ur code but it is giving converted date as: Mon Jan 07 00:00:00 GMT+5:30 2013. I want just "2013-01-07" that is yyyy-MM-dd.

Comment: @Dhwani: Well, yes, that's the string representation of a `Date`; e.g. what you get when you call `start.toString()`. If you want to format a date in a specific string representation, then use `SimpleDateFormat` again. For example: `formatter.format(start)` (using above variables) will give you the date represented by `start` in `"yyyy-MM-dd"` format. However, this is quite the opposite of what you were initially asking for...

Comment: But when I compare it with a date, It is giving me wrong results so I was checking through Toast.

Comment: @Dhwani: Please add the code you use to do the comparison, the result you get and the result you were expecting.

Comment: @Dhwani: I've updated my answer based on the code you added. However, 2 out of the 3 questions from my previous comment remain unanswered. I'm happy to help, but you're not really being very generous with details...

Comment: I am getting json file's date f=in date field. I have added comment to my code now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22161/discussion-between-dhwani-and-mh)

Answer (score 0):

If you explode the date by dash - it will be easy to compare dates between mobile date and date by json. with easy compare logic you will get it.

```
String date = "2013-02-15";
String[] separated = date.split("-");
separated[0]; // this will contain "2013"
separated[1]; // this will contain "02"
separated[2]; // this will contain "15"

Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance(); 
String date =  c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Calendar ( to get mobile date )
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: But i want to compare two dates.

Comment: what do you mean by compare ? you already get the date by json with previous comment. 

`Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance(); 
String date =  c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);`

you can compare date with separated[2]

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
boolean isBefore = new Date().before(sdf.parse("2013-02-15",0));
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html